# Foreach loop in Ghost CMS returning null

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

Currently setting up a simple site using Ghost CMS. By default, the homepage comes with a list of posts that it retrieves through a `foreach` loop. I'm trying to recreate that on the posts page, but nothing is being pulled in.

File structure is:

```
/theme
/theme/index.hbs
/theme/post.hbs
```

The code that works on the `index.hbs` is:

```
{{#foreach posts}}
<article class="{{post_class}}">
    <header class="post-header">
        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="{{url}}">{{{title}}}</a></h2>
    </header>
    <section class="post-excerpt">
        <p>{{excerpt words="26"}} <a class="read-more" href="{{url}}">&raquo;</a></p>
    </section>
    <footer class="post-meta">
        {{#if author.image}}<img class="author-thumb" src="{{author.image}}" alt="Author image" nopin="nopin" />{{/if}}
        {{author}}
        {{tags prefix=" on "}}
        <time class="post-date" datetime="{{date format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}">{{date format="DD MMMM YYYY"}}</time>
    </footer>
</article>
{{/foreach}}
```

My slightly stripped down version that I use on the `post.hbs` page is:

```
<aside class="timeline">
    {{#foreach posts}}
        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="{{url}}">{{{title}}}</a></h4>
        <section class="post-meta">
            {{author}}
            {{tags prefix=" on "}}
            <time class="post-date" datetime="{{date format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}">{{date format="DD MMMM YYYY"}}</time>
        </section>
    {{/foreach}}
</aside>
```

My guess is that I can't call posts while on the post page, but I'm not sure.

Comment: not 100% sure on how ghost works but my normal operation with handlebars is my js gets the data then passes it to the handlebars template, the way your question is worded it seems like you expect the handlebars template to be pulling in the posts it's self, kind of like how wordpress might do it

Comment: I believe you guess is correct. You can't call `posts` on `post.hbs`. You could use the RSS feed to generate a list with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop through all the posts on a post page. The post page is specifically for a single post. You can create custom static pages though which sounds like what you want.

What you want to do, is create a blank post with a title and page url (lets say the page url is `blog.com/stuff`). Make this post a static page. Then in your theme files, create a new file called `page-stuff.hbs` (stuff being the url of the static page). Then here you can do the foreach loop for the posts and grab whatever you want.

- [Info on creating a static page](http://ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-publish-a-page-on-your-ghost-blog/)
- [Info on custom page template](http://themes.ghost.org/v0.5.5/docs/structure#page-hbs)